# How to write xsl to get the value of all duplicate tag?

Tags: xml, xslt

I need some help with writing xsl.

I have xml data as below.

```xml
<Data>
  <so_offer_display_value action="add">XXXX</so_offer_display_value>
  <so_offer_id action="add">51005577</so_offer_id>
  <so_offer_view_id action="add">3932079043</so_offer_view_id>
  <so_offer_display_value action="add">YYYYY</so_offer_display_value>
  <so_offer_id action="add">51005541</so_offer_id>
  <so_offer_view_id action="add">3932080043</so_offer_view_id>
</Data>
```

My intended output is:

```xml
<inst>
  <offerId>51005577</offerId>
  <instId>3932079043</instId>
  <Description>XXXX</Description>
  <Action>Add</Action>
</inst>
<inst>
  <offerId>51005541</offerId>
  <instId>3932080043</instId>
  <Description>YYYY</Description>
  <Action>Add</Action>
</inst>
```

I am trying like below, but it is printing same value twice.

```xslt
<xsl:if test="/Data/so_offer_id/@action = 'add'">
  <xsl:for-each select="/Data/so_offer_id">
    <inst>
      <offerId>
        <xsl:value-of select="/Data/so_offer_id[@action='add']"/>
      </offerId>
      <instId>
        <xsl:value-of select="/Data/so_offer_view_id[@action='add']"/>
      </instId>
      <Description>
        <xsl:value-of select="/Data/so_offer_display_value[@action='add']"/>
      </Description>
      <Action>Add</Action>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    </inst>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below you have a solution based on a *key*.
The advantage of this solution is that source tags within `Data` can be in any order.

The first output `inst` tag contains first tags with respective names.
The second output `inst` tag contains second tags and so on.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="tags" match="Data/*" use="name()"/>

  <xsl:template match="Data">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each select="so_offer_id">
        <xsl:element name="inst">
          <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
          <xsl:element name="offerId">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </xsl:element>
          <xsl:element name="instId">
            <xsl:value-of select="key('tags', 'so_offer_view_id')[$pos]"/>
          </xsl:element>
          <xsl:element name="Description">
            <xsl:value-of select="key('tags', 'so_offer_display_value')[$pos]"/>
          </xsl:element>
          <Action>Add</Action>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The key doesn't really do anything useful here. Instead of `<xsl:value-of select="key('tags', 'so_offer_view_id')[$pos]"/>` you could have said simply `<xsl:value-of select="../so_offer_view_id[$pos]"/>`.

Comment: P.S. I didn't think you could use the index alone, because the question suggests there may be intervening items whose `action` is not "add". But if the OP is happy ...

Comment: I think that *key* works quicker than "ordinary" selection with a pattern. It is especially important for big volume input.

Comment: Not in this case, where the selection is by name. The nodes are already indexed by their name and by their position in the context node-set.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Data">
    <xsl:for-each select="so_offer_id[@action='add']">  
        <inst>
            <offerId>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </offerId>
            <instId>
                <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::so_offer_view_id[1]"/>
            </instId>
            <Description>
                <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::so_offer_display_value[1]"/>
            </Description>
            <Action>Add</Action>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        </inst>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is assuming each instance of offer has the same 3 nodes, in the same order.

Note that the result is not a well-formed XML document, because it does not have a single root element.

Comment: Is there any way to improve further to get rid of ordering of input xml? As in my case, input xml will be generated by another job and it can appear in any order.

Comment: Then you need to clarify how to identify the nodes that need to be grouped together into the same `inst`.